# Correct way to send file via socket in java after a GET request from browser

Tags: java, sockets

I am using a brower to send a get request to a server by simply typing the address 127.0.0.1:1501/filename.png. The purpose is to download a file from the server. The server is successful in receiving the request and loading the chosen file, it also enters the while loop and executes the print method several times meaning that something is sending, but inspecting on google chrome in the "network" tab I only get filename.png failed
I can't understand why this code doesn't seem to work.
print is a method that simply call the System.out.println() method

```
public class MainClassServer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServerSocket server = null;
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            server.bind(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1501));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        while(true) {
            String message;
            Socket client = null;
            print("Waiting for client...");
            try{
                client = server.accept();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            DataOutputStream writer = null;

            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                writer = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(client.getOutputStream()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                message = reader.readLine();

                if(message!=null) {
                    //I get the correct filename with string manipulation
                    // I correctly access the file in fact it exist
                    File file = new File(path);

                    if(file.exists()) {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
                        int count;
                        while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                            //the program print some bytes so it writes something to someone
                            print("Sending " + count + " bytes");
                            writer.write(bytes, 0, count);
                        }
                        writer.flush();
                    }else {
                        print("File does not exsist.");
                    }


                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                    server.close();
                    break;  
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: To send data to a web browser you need to send the appropriate `HTTP Response Header` which specifies the content type and length. Otherwise, the browser doesn't know how to interpret the data.

Comment: You have to send back an HTTP status line containing an HTTP version number, followed by a success/failure error code, followed by a human-readable status text. Then send HTTP headers describing the file's type, length, transfer format, etc. Then finally send the file's bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Browser always expects HTTP Response in return when it requests. If you have client which is simple socket client, you will get the file as you're writing in `DataOutputStream` for HTTP atleast you need minimum HTTP response format. If you add these 2 headers in your response you may get the expected behavior.

```
if(file.exists()) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
    int count;
    // Setting HTTP response headers
    writer.writeBytes("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
    writer.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n");
    writer.writeBytes("\r\n");
    while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
        //the program print some bytes so it writes something to someone
        print("Sending " + count + " bytes");
        writer.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }
    writer.flush();
}else {
    print("File does not exsist.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are NOT following the [HTTP 1.x protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) at all, not even close:

- you are NOT reading and parsing the browser's HTTP request. You are reading only the 1st line of the request, ignoring the rest of the request (there can be, and usually is, more than 1 line).  And you are not even parsing that 1st line - there is more data in it than just a file path.  It contains the request method name (ie, `GET`), followed by the file path, followed by an HTTP version number.
- you are NOT sending back a properly formatted HTTP response. You are just sending the raw file bytes as-is, without telling the client whether the request was even successful or not, or describing what kind of file data you are sending.  You have to send back an HTTP status line containing an HTTP version number, followed by a success/failure error code, followed by a human-readable status text.  Then send HTTP headers describing the file's type, length, transfer format, etc.  Then finally send the file's bytes.

Basically, what you have implemented so far is an [HTTP 0.9](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) server (which does use single-line requests - which you are still not parsing it correctly - and no extra response details beyond the file's raw bytes).  This kind of server won't work for HTTP 1.0+ requests, which all modern web browsers use.  HTTP 1.1 is the de-factor standard right now that most modern systems use (though many are starting to make the transition to [HTTP/2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540)).

You really should be using a proper HTTP server, not a plain vanilla TCP server.  HTTP is complex and not trivial to implement from scratch.  You should use a pre-existing implementation instead.  For instance, Java has a built-in [`HttpServer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html) class.